# Problems with using external login and sending confirmation mail in asp.NET core identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to set up a web app with authentication via a google API, using the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#prevent-login-at-registration) from microsoft.

My ConfigureServices looks like this:

```cs
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle(options =>
                 {
                     IConfigurationSection googleAuthNSection =
                     Configuration.GetSection("Authentication:Google");
                     options.ClientId = googleAuthNSection["ClientId"];
                     options.ClientSecret = googleAuthNSection["ClientSecret"];
                     options.CallbackPath = "/oauth2callback";
                 });
            services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
        }
```

I have set up SendGrid to send mails for activating the accounts.

However, when I am registering an account with the google API, the confirmation mail is not sent, and I can't activate the account. This works just fine when I am registering an account with just an e-mail address.

The confirmation mail is sent when I set the `SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount` to false. But why do I have to do this? It does not make sense to me that the confirmation mail is only being sent in case the account confirmation is not required. I also don't want to set this to false because otherwise you can log on without confirmation.

I am using .NET core 3.0

Comment: Have you found a reason?

Comment: Not yet, I have asked it on an existing issue on github: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/13206

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly same issue when using .netCore 3.1 and Blazor server side app.
Instead SendGrid I am using my custom email sender but the result is exactly same. Confirmation email is only sent when I create local account. When authenticating via external providers no email is sent and therefore no way to confirm the account and login into the app.

I fixed this by setting this in my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => 
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        })
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

That did the trick. User after registration is automatically logged to the app but after he logouts and did not confirm his email is not allowed to login again. Also that way email message is sent no matter if it was local account registered or the one from 3rd party (Google, Facebook, etc.).